# iOS5 and Facebook SDK 3.01/Facebook feed

Tags: objective-c, facebook, ios5

I'm going crazy.  I've installed the Facebook SDK 3.01.  I've added it to my frameworks.  I've imported it into my view controller.  I'm using the code from the Facebook developers' page, as follows:

```
UIImage *pic = [self createImage];
NSString *list = self.haiku_text.text;
NSString *kAppId=@"xxxxxxxxx0507";
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:kAppId, @"app_id",nil, @"link", pic, @"picture",@"Haiku", @"name",nil, @"caption",@"Maybe he'll love me if I give him a haiku....",@"description",nil];
[facebook dialog:@"feed"
       andParams:params
     andDelegate:self];
```

And no matter what I do I get a `use of undeclared identifier 'facebook'` error.  This suggests to me that `facebook` needs to be an instantiation of some class or property--but I've been looking for what feels like millennia and I can't find out anywhere what that class or property is.  What I've read on stackoverflow makes me think it used to have something to do with FBConnect, but that doesn't seem to exist in the new Facebook SDK.

Any thoughts that will help me keep at least a little of the hair I'm tearing out?